# Regex for mod rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to write regex for my .htaccess file that will redirect user from
`test-john-doe.html` to `person.php?id=john-doe`

I tried this RewriteRule

```
^test-/([a-z0-9-]+).html/$ person.php?id=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any idea anyone?

Comment: There are many places to test regex online. You should try one of them and see if it provides you insight. You can also read [the how-to-ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what information you should include in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex looks a little overcomplicated, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test-([^/]+)\.html$ /person.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra trailing slash and you must escape dot in a regex:

```
RewriteRule ^test-/([a-z0-9-]+?)\.html$ person.php?id=$1 [R=301,L]
```